# Sharepoint 2010 business connectivity services connection to Web services

Tags: sharepoint-2010, bcs

While learning BCS I've been given a task to create connection with any web service ( like google weather and stuff) and display it on sharepoint site. I've made connection to sql table in my previous task and I've seen such tutorials as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556431(v=office.14).aspx
which is she most related to my task that I've been able to find.
If any one could share any tutorial of how to make connection to web service, or suply **working** example of bdc model I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In like a week of searching I've been able to find a single article  that would answer my question. I do not know why this information is missed in like all bcs books, and even in Microsoft SP course for professionals. Any way here is the article I hope it will help someone. 
http://netsourcecode.blogspot.ru/2010/10/business-data-connectivity-and-web.html